# What is the most suitable control to use for 3D rendering and animation programming in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, graphics

I am researching 3D and 2D rendering animation. I found the PictureBox control
is pretty okay for this purpose, but I feel I have only very beginner level knowledge. I am curious to know if it is possible to make a moderately complex level of rendering applications with the PictureBox control. In short, which is the best control in the Windows application tool box to be selected for my intended purpose?

I am making a Windows Forms application with C#.

Comment: WinForms is not designed for 3D rendering and animation, so you are probably barking up the wrong tree. It is very difficult to give any more specific answer, since "3D rendering and animation programming" is such a nebulous and ill-defined term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are doing with the PictureBox control for this purpose. But if you're using Windows Forms, then you may want to consider making your own Control subclass with all of your drawing operations handled using GDI+ calls in the OnPaint method. You could pair this with a Timer object called every so often to determine when to refresh.

This is an approach I have personally used for drawing previews of simulated mechanical objects in 2D, so this might work for your purposes as well.

Unless you can tell us what exactly you are trying to draw or provide some existing code for us to look at, it will be hard to give you a precise answer. But MSDN has some pages covering this topic, which you can take a look at to get started and for further reading:

- [Custom Control Painting and Rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Rendering a Windows Forms Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e430ef4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [User-Drawn Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Control.OnPaint Method (PaintEventArgs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Graphics Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply !!

My intention is to make some animation for fluid dynamic properties which I have to display its different geometrical shapes and need to move/rotate XYZ directions. I don't know WPF, I felt WinForms are simple and if the application is complex only at moderate level why can't I try with a Winform application so only concern is to spot the best control/widget from the toolkit.

Comment: @Sonu Unfortunately, I don't think Windows Forms has a control available by default for displaying 3D objects. As I see it, your options are to 1) follow my advice from this answer, but implement your own code for projecting your 3D objects into a 2D representation (which TBH I have not tried before and would likely be quite complex), 2) find and use a 3rd-party control or library for implementing this in Windows Forms, or 3) select a different GUI toolkit which provides better default support for this. The last two would be subjective recommendations at best, and outside SO's scope.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks very much for your advice, it really helped to me save lot of time for unnecessary researches

Answer (score 0):

The latest libraries you can use are from Xamarin,

- [SkiaSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/)
- [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/)

They wrap over Skia and Urho engine so that you can render 2D or 3D contents in WinForms or WPF or any other kind of applications.

Comment: The question is for Windows Forms, not Xamarin.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton If you don't read the articles, don't say any words please.

Comment: I read the "articles". Do you work for Xamarin? Because this looks more like spam than an answer to the question.

Comment: Instead downvoting this, please vote to close the question itself like I did before posting this answer.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, I read the documentation you have linked to. But they only appear to be usable with Xamarin Forms... unless you can point to an example or tutorial where Windows Forms is explicitly used to host these?

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton "SkiaSharp is a Portable Library, and ships conveniently as a cross-platform NuGet package, and supports the following platforms out of the box: macOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and the Windows Desktop." where Windows Desktop means WinForms and WPF. Well, I don't expect anyone to be quite familiar with Xamarin technologies, but down voting in that manner does not make things better.

Comment: @LexLi I took another, closer look. [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/platform/windows/) states it could be used with WPF or Windows Forms (as long as the target is 64-bit Windows). SkiaSharp does not mention quite the same thing, but if UrhoSharp could be used then I assume that might be compatible as well. Downvote withdrawn.

Comment: @LexLi, Thanks very much for your answer !!!  I have to go through your URLs to understand